# Maven: build only changed modules and create WAR as fast as possible

Tags: maven, war

I have project with following maven modules:

PARENT:

```
  <modules>
    <module>../api</module>
    <module>../model</module>
    <module>../server</module>
  </modules>
```

API:

```
 <dependency>           
    <artifactId>model</artifactId>
 </dependency>
```

MODEL:
     (without dependencies to other modules)

SERVER:

```
<dependency>
    <artifactId>model</artifactId>          
</dependency>
<dependency>            
    <artifactId>api</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Now, when I change anything in source code I have to perform *mvn clean install* for parent project in order to create war file. Its too long and I would like to know if there is any other convenient way to create war without rebuilding unnecessary modules. For example, under eclipse environment I can choose *build* and it makes new WAR really fast without rebuilding all modules. How can I do it manually from maven ?

Comment: Why are you cleaning?

Answer (score 2):

Just skip the execution of clean for starters. This way it will only compile changed classes and perform a number of others steps only incrementally depending on what is required.

Beyond that you could look at using the takari lifecycle and the related M2e tooling.

You can also select to only rebuild project that have changed and their dependencies.

Comment: So, should I use only *maven install -DskipTests* for parent project ?